# i3 Super doesn't work after changing keyboard layout

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout, i3

I recently got an external keyboard for my laptop. Problem is that I have to use i3 at school and that whenever I'm changing my keyboard layout (because default layout is french and I got an US keyboard) my Super is not working anymore. Either on the external keyboard or the laptop layout. When I'm on Ubuntu, everything is working fine.

PS : I changed the keyboard layout through the command setxkbmap -layout us